# How to effectively attach mirrored stickers to an interior curved surface?

Tags: building, stickers

I'm working on 10283, Space Shuttle Discovery and I've reached pack 13 step 282 where I'm assembling the cargo bay doors. These doors have reflective stickers that attach to the insides of the curved surface. These stickers are also somewhat large - about 1.5" by 1" (~3x2 cm), which makes getting them properly aligned doubly complicated... *plus* the reflective quality makes it really easy to scratch or get wrong.

I've only done one so far and I'm not super happy - it's been really complicated to get the placement and keep the position without it skidding on the curved surface. It's really tempting to rest it against the vertical surface without leaving any border space but, when I did, I get ripples that are really obvious due to that being where TLG put the piece info. Here's the one I've done already:

[image: Fingers holding a lego piece with mirrored stickers applied on the inner side of the LEGO. There are three stickers and the center, largest sticker has slight bubbles, which are noticeable due to the warped reflection in the sticker]

I did review the answers to  [What are some helpful techniques for applying stickers?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/881/what-are-some-helpful-techniques-for-applying-stickers) but these seem to focus on smaller stickers that are surface mounted and that's not really the issue I'm having here. I'm hoping to find some guidance that's specific to curved interior surfaces.